# In closures we know for each loop iteration variable "i" is a fresh copy, then why const "i" not work in a loop

Tags: javascript, constants

This code works and each callback is referencing a different `i` it indicates that for each loop iteration a new copy of `i` is created, due to that the callback forms a closure with a distinct "i" each time

```
const arr = [10, 12, 15, 21];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: '+ arr[i]);
  }, 3000)
}
```

This gives error: Assignment to constant variable.
Why, in this case, isn't a new constant `i` is created for each loop iteration?

```
const arr = [10, 12, 15, 21];
for (const i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: '+ arr[i]);
  }, 3000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a constant must not be changed, you can't i++ on a constant.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 1):

`++i` doesn't modify the instance of `i` - it creates a new instance with an incremented value and assigns it back to `i`.  If `i` is defined as a `const`, you cannot assign the value back to it, and hence the error.

Comment: If ++i creates a new instance in first case then why in second case it didn't create a new instance and assigned back value to it

Comment: @nt314 I don't understand this sentence

Comment: If for each loop iteration a new instance of "i" is created then why in the second piece of code for each loop iteration a new copy of a constant variable i with incremented value not getting created?

Comment: @nt314 as I explained - it errors out because you can't (implicitly) reassign the value back to `i`.

Comment: @nt314  For each loop of case one, a new "i" is NOT created. the first bit `let i = 0` only runs once, and then in every loop it is modified. The second case also only has the one instance of "i" - but it becomes a syntax error immediately, as the loop wishes to mutate what "i" references.